# Compare performance with and without cache using django redis

Tags: django, caching, redis

I am using redis to implement caching for django project, I have created two function to compare the performance but function with caching seems slow any reason to that.
*Here is the loadtest output for the function without caching*

```
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Max requests:        50
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Concurrency level:   1
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Agent:               none
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO 
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Completed requests:  50
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Total errors:        0
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Total time:          0.40408834 s
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Requests per second: 124
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:48:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Mean latency:        8 ms
```

and is the loadtest output for the function with caching

```
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Max requests:        50
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Concurrency level:   1
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Agent:               none
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO 
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Completed requests:  50
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Total errors:        0
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Total time:          18.811554342 s
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Requests per second: 3
[Thu Mar 23 2023 17:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] INFO Mean latency:        376.1 ms
```

Person and Person1 are function with and without cache respectively.

```
def person(request):       
    if 'auth' in request.session and  request.session['auth']:
        res_all = Person.objects.values().all()

        return render(request,'blog.html',context={"all_data":res_all})
    else:
        return render(request,'blog.html',context={})


def person1(request):
    cache_data=cache.get('cache_key_person')
    if cache_data:
        return render(request,'blog.html',context={"all_data":cache_data})
    else:
        res_all = Person.objects.values().all()            
        cache.set('cache_key_person', res_all, CACHE_TTL) 
        return render(request,'blog.html',context={"all_data":res_all})
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier if you would show these functions

Comment: @PTomasz, added the functions.